# How can I get my NAV text to stop moving on hover?

Tags: css, navigation, hover

I added a border/line above [my nav links](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com) on hover, except now it moves my text down each time you hover over it. What is causing that?

```
#nav a:hover{
border-top:solid 4px #3b5998; 
color:#b7c3e6; 
padding: 6px}


.header-alignment-left.header-navigation-split #topNav{position:absolute; right:-15px}

.logo-image #topNav nav li a{padding:5px 15px; line-height:100%}
#nav a{border-top:0px solid transparent}
#nav .subnav{margin-top:0}

#nav a{border-right:1.5px solid #3b5998; height:20px}
#nav li:last-child a{border-right:0}

#topNav nav .folder ul li a {   
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out  }

#header #topNav nav .folder ul li{padding:0 24px 12px; position:relative; } 
#header{margin-top:20px !important}
#topNav{margin-top:40px}
#nav .subnav ul{padding-bottom:15px !important}
#nav .subnav ul{padding-top:15px !important}
```

Comment: reduce the padding on the hover and it should stop moving

Comment: Do you not want it hoping down like it is right now?

Comment: @ZeroPhase no, I dont want it to move, it started moving when i added the line above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign it a `margin`

Something like this should work.

```
#nav a:hover{
border-top:solid 4px #3b5998; 
color:#b7c3e6;
margin-top: 10px; 
padding: 6px}
```

You can even use negative `margins` if needed.

You might want to remove the `padding` and replace it with `padding-left` or `padding-right` so you don't move the top and bottom of the link.

Comment: i tried this, and it moved it more. I tried negative margin, and it moved it the other direction.

Comment: Try playing around with the `position` property for the page.  You have a lot of markup in there, so if you could break all of the parts responsible for controlling the `nav` into a jsfiddle.net it would help with debugging.

Comment: added the rest of my NAV css in my question. Its a template site from squarespace, so something i added above is causing it I think. I dont know how to build the jfiddle thing.

Comment: The `border` and `padding` are adding to the thickness and causing it the nav to hop down/ up.  what you can do is photoshop an image of a line, and access the file with `background-image:url(filepath); background-position: 0px 105px;` You might also need to set the `z-index` elements with `z-indexes` render in terms of the order they are assigned. Lower numbers force elements into the background and higher numbers force them forward.